# Express-jwt Throwing UnathorizedError: No Authorization Token was found in IE11 when Chrome and Firefox work

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, angular-fullstack, express-jwt

I have tracked the issue down to this call:

```
var validateJwt = expressJwt({
  secret: config.secrets.session
});
```

using the latest version of express-jwt

here is the full file

```
( auth.service.js from the angular-generator yeoman scafolding)

/**
 * Attaches the user object to the request if authenticated
 * Otherwise returns 403
 */
export function isAuthenticated() {
  return compose()
    // Validate jwt
    .use(function(req, res, next) {
      // allow access_token to be passed through query parameter as well
      if (req.query && req.query.hasOwnProperty('access_token')) {
        req.headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + req.query.access_token;
      }
      console.log('In Auth Service');
      console.log('Secret=' + config.secrets.session);
      validateJwt(req, res, next);
    })
    // Attach user to request
    .use(function(req, res, next) {
      console.log('Attach User');
      User.findByIdAsync(req.user._id)
        .then(user => {
          if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).end();
          }
          req.user = user;
          next();
        })
        .catch(err => next(err));
    });
}
```

I see the "In Auth Service" log in IE and then this error:

```
   UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at middleware (.../node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:80:21)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Middleware_Common_Object.&lt;anonymous&gt; (.../server/auth/auth.service.js:27:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (.../node_modules/composable-middleware/lib/composable-middleware.js:59:18)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Middleware_Common_Object.middleware (.../node_modules/composable-middleware/lib/composable-middleware.js:76:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at middleware (.../node_modules/composable-middleware/lib/composable-middleware.js:31:25)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (.../node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (.../node_modules/expres
```

In Chrome and Firefox this works fine and I see the log "Attach User".

I'm not an express or jwt (or javascript for that matter) expert so any thoughts as to why this doesn't work on IE? I can't login to my application in IE11.

Headers for Chrome:

Head

```
{  
   "host":"localhost:9000",
   "connection":"keep-alive",
   "accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*",
   "x-xsrf-token":"XyZYPphsmONBmSrE1MoiMh4zcclJhvArkppVM=",
   "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36",
   "authorization":"Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1NzE1ODg0MjEyZTU3OTFkMzEwZmQ1MTMiLCJyb2xlIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0NjQyODQwNDMsImV4cCI6MTQ2NDMwMjA0M30.YJj4LaHdhRtzfr0AdjTkZwTZM2M4B0YSoR3qactkq8o",
   "referer":"http://localhost:9000/login",
   "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, sdch",
   "accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.8",
   "cookie":"connect.sid=s%3AZBJISBM2X82Odr1f763gL_hOJPCTy75G.ePulOt7zpqSQ6WHmPVqMKsjFVboteA8ALhBcR6f4J70; _gat=1; _ga=GA1.1.1107287728.1463674097; token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1NzE1ODg0MjEyZTU3OTFkMzEwZmQ1MTMiLCJyb2xlIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0NjQyODQwNDMsImV4cCI6MTQ2NDMwMjA0M30.YJj4LaHdhRtzfr0AdjTkZwTZM2M4B0YSoR3qactkq8o; XSRF-TOKEN=XyZYPphsmONBmSrE1MoiMh4zcclJhvArkppVM%3D",
   "if-none-match":"W/\"2-11FxOYiYfpMxmANj4kGJzg\""
}
```

//Body was empty...

Body = {}

getting IE ...

IE11:
Head

```
{  
   "x-xsrf-token":"VnE872wcJGAcsDuqFPo4yX3eHCjib8+VuohJY=",
   "accept":"application/json, text/plain, /",
   "referer":"http://172.20.10.2:9000/login",
   "accept-language":"en-US",
   "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate",
   "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
   "host":"172.20.10.2:9000",
   "dnt":"1",
   "connection":"Keep-Alive",
   "cookie":"XSRF-TOKEN=VnE872wcJGAcsDuqFPo4yX3eHCjib8%2BVuohJY%3D; connect.sid=s%3A-cBMyw42buDZePLCriiGqddXI2YSg5Ow.HKcDCPksLX7PIYpp9O1XK2aDUh%2BycceyNywDN8TZOTU; _ga=GA1.4.1855210034.1464283317; _gat=1; token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1NzE1ODg0MjEyZTU3OTFkMzEwZmQ1MTMiLCJyb2xlIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0NjQyODQwODgsImV4cCI6MTQ2NDMwMjA4OH0.-BF00BbZknsIjAcX-EDNMtwgKaw4UFDA-Ywm4-gTlNI"
}
```

//body empty
Body = {}

and this error popped up.
UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found

Adding Req.query (just from IE - empty also empty on Chrome)

Head

{"x-xsrf-token":"Q9WJPpcGYhLyBn1YX1I8asymB1rVtTfLN1ZJk=","accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","referer":"http://172.20.10.2:9000/login","accept-language":"en-US","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko","host":"172.20.10.2:9000","dnt":"1","connection":"Keep-Alive","cookie":"_ga=GA1.4.1855210034.1464283317; _gat=1; XSRF-TOKEN=Q9WJPpcGYhLyBn1YX1I8asymB1rVtTfLN1ZJk%3D; connect.sid=s%3ANvaz9AfTMU3t0CDq-3aRzSIF7Uw_bmfh.GV6s5MXKpk3XiULQbmQrJR2w7QAuJxUb0BGCYfmjuic; token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1NzE1ODg0MjEyZTU3OTFkMzEwZmQ1MTMiLCJyb2xlIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0NjQyODg3NzcsImV4cCI6MTQ2NDMwNjc3N30.zCsSkIdHlcCmPUHvhNv5n2mkgQDhkxG9UO0sh3y-Y3c"}
Body =

{}
ReqQuery

{}

///After trying Eric's suggesting and implementing the code change associated with the fix on the angular-fullstack code I got this for a header on IE. (but unfortunately didn't log in - got a 401 on the /api/user/me. part. I'm going to revert back some further changes later today that i may have done last night when i was too tired.

Head

{"accept":"application/json, text/plain,
*/*","if-modified-since":"Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT","cache-control":"no-cache","pragma":"no-cache","x-xsrf-token":"Ajy7jYPUQj7Mnixtqq8rvJRyxj/pv6s2P36eo=","referer":"http://192.168.1.17:9000/login?auth_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.e%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8ByJfaWQiOiI1NzE1ODg0MjEyZTU3OTFkMzEwZmQ1MTMiLCJyb2xlIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0NjQyOD%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8BQwNDMsImV4cCI6MTQ2NDMwMjA0M30.YJj4LaHdhRtzfr0AdjTkZwTZM2M4B0YSoR3qactkq8o","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.5","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko","host":"192.168.1.17:9000","dnt":"1","connection":"Keep-Alive","cookie":"XSRF-TOKEN=Ajy7jYPUQj7Mnixtqq8rvJRyxj%2Fpv6s2P36eo%3D; connect.sid=s%3A43OG6niC7AAUnnOQ2cnbZe0mW1Qx6Ag5.xi0KLw9FbkMOWIofcbuTXBNDGxZXfZu87XXDxZDNO6A;
_ga=GA1.4.540511734.1464357176; _gat=1; token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1NzE1ODg0MjEyZTU3OTFkMzEwZmQ1MTMiLCJyb2xlIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0NjQzNTc4NjIsImV4cCI6MTQ2NDM3NTg2Mn0.Si_4hZuntOLWwYpT2WGEKVpYi36WA3_aiuHZj7445LY"}

Body = {}
Req Query = {}

///Adding what I think is the code to add the authorization header
I appreciate everyones time for looking into this with me!

```
function authInterceptor($rootScope, $q, $cookies, $injector, Util) {
  var state;
  return {
    // Add authorization token to headers
    request(config) {
      config.headers = config.headers || {};
      if ($cookies.get('token') && Util.isSameOrigin(config.url)) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookies.get('token');
      }
      return config;
    },

    // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
    responseError(response) {
      if (response.status === 401) {
        (state || (state = $injector.get('$state'))).go('login');
        // remove any stale tokens
        $cookies.remove('token');
      }
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: can you include a dump header and body from the `req` object. One for Chome/Firefox and another for IE11

Comment: Sure - suggestions on how to do this? I'll google how to do it tomorrow and paste it in (Limping through my startup saas coding - looking for a solid employee #1 as well)

Comment: I assume just console log the req object, don't need any packet sniffer right?

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(req.head)) and the same for the body

Comment: Attached the headers to the question. the body is empty

Comment: Sorry can you dump `req.query` as well - but as an initial stab it looks like `authorization` is not being set in IE headers check your code around that.

Comment: ok will do - not sure why it would be different for ie vs the others.. dumping the req.query ( i think it was empty if I recall)

Comment: updated ( i can't move this to a chat because its my first ) - the query is empty

Comment: Can you temporarily edit your request your client side code for to include the token as a param i.e. `http://172.20.10.2:9000/login?auth_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1NzE1ODg0MjEyZTU3OTFkMzEwZmQ1MTMiLCJyb2xlIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0NjQyODQwNDMsImV4cCI6MTQ2NDMwMjA0M30.YJj4LaHdhRtzfr0AdjTkZwTZM2M4B0YSoR3qactkq8o`

This should at leat prove that you can login from IE and there is an issue client side setting the authorization header.

Can you share your client side code generating the requests and setting the headers?

Comment: user1136560 - that didn't work (but i just tried the link you sent) i'll have more time this afternoon. I think Erik might be onto something I did use the angular-fullstack generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have stumbled on this known issue in angular-fullstack: https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/1880

That thread also shows the fix that has been committed in the latest source code, that you can implement manually in your generated code (commenting out a port number check in the code that otherwise fails in IE).

Comment: I added that code. I think I'm getting closer. I'll have more time later to look into it. I posted an updated header in my question.. ( I also added port 9000 since that's what im pushing out to locally). Thanks for that - i think its something around the answer.

Comment: by the way that didn't work straight out of the box.. something else too look at though because I hadn't even been in that file.